# How can I program a photo wall using Gstreamer in C?

Tags: c, image, gstreamer

I'm trying to simulate the following gstreamer pipeline in C. I want to use pictures from a website instead of videos.

```
gst-launch -e videomixer name=mix ! ffmpegcolorspace ! xvimagesink \
videotestsrc pattern=1 ! video/x-raw-yuv,framerate=5/1,width=320,height=180 ! videobox     border-alpha=0 top=0 left=0 ! mix. \
videotestsrc pattern=15 ! video/x-raw-yuv,framerate=5/1,width=320,height=180 ! videobox border-alpha=0 top=0 left=-320 ! mix. \
videotestsrc pattern=13 ! video/x-raw-yuv,framerate=5/1,width=320,height=180 ! videobox border-alpha=0 top=-180 left=0 ! mix. \
videotestsrc pattern=0 ! video/x-raw-yuv,framerate=5/1,width=320,height=180 ! videobox border-alpha=0 top=-180 left=-320 ! mix. \
videotestsrc pattern=3 ! video/x-raw-yuv,framerate=5/1,width=640,height=360 ! mix.
```

So this is an extract from my code (I try with only two pictures) :

```
void display_logo (struct Radio radio[]){

GMainLoop *loop;

GstElement *pipeline,*freeze,*clrspace;
GstElement *source[2];
GstElement *videobox1,*videobox2;
GstElement *mixer,*sink,*queuevideo;
GstBus *bus;

loop = g_main_loop_new (NULL, FALSE);

/* Create gstreamer elements */
pipeline = gst_pipeline_new ("player");
source[0]  = gst_element_factory_make ("playbin2", "dec1");
source[1]  = gst_element_factory_make ("playbin2", "dec2");
freeze = gst_element_factory_make ("imagefreeze", "fr");
//videobox1 = gst_element_factory_make ("videobox",       "videobox1");
//videobox2 = gst_element_factory_make ("videobox",       "videobox2");
clrspace  = gst_element_factory_make ("ffmpegcolorspace",       "clrspace");
mixer = gst_element_factory_make ("videomixer",       "mixer");
queuevideo = gst_element_factory_make ("queue", "queue-video");
sink     = gst_element_factory_make ("autovideosink", "sink");


if (!pipeline || !source[0] || source[1] !sink || !mixer ||!freeze || !clrspace ||!queuevideo ) {
    g_printerr ("One element could not be created. Exiting.\n");
    exit(1);
}

g_object_set (source[0], "uri", radio[0].logo, NULL);
g_object_set (source[1], "uri", radio[1].logo, NULL);

// g_object_set(videobox1,"border-alpha",0,"top",0,"left",0,NULL);
// g_object_set(videobox2,"border-alpha",0,"top",0,"left",-200,NULL);

/* we add a message handler */
bus = gst_pipeline_get_bus (GST_PIPELINE (pipeline));
gst_bus_add_watch (bus, bus_call, loop);
gst_object_unref (bus);

/* we add all elements into the pipeline */
gst_bin_add_many (GST_BIN (pipeline),
                  source[0],mixer, clrspace, freeze, sink, source[1], NULL);

/* we link the elements together */
gst_element_link_many (source[0], mixer, clrspace, freeze,sink,source[1], NULL);
//gst_element_link_many (source[1], mixer, NULL);

 g_signal_connect (source[0], "pad-added", G_CALLBACK (on_pad_added), queuevideo);
 g_signal_connect (source[1], "pad-added", G_CALLBACK (on_pad_added), queuevideo);


/* Set the pipeline to "playing" state*/
gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);

/* Iterate */
g_print ("Running...\n");
g_main_loop_run (loop);

/* Out of the main loop, clean up nicely */
g_print ("Returned, stopping playback\n");
gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);

g_print ("Deleting pipeline\n");
gst_object_unref (GST_OBJECT (pipeline));
}
```

When I run the code, I have 3 windows (1 green and 2 with the pictures). I tried with videobox but it didn't change anything. How can I have the two pictures in the same window ?

Answer (score 0):

So basically you want to do compositing of the images ie given images 1 2 3 4 produce this image for instance of all images can you post more details to help you what you have in the Radio struct ?because i don't show image URL in your code

Comment: Here is an example of what I want to do : http://www.casimages.com/img.php?i=131030084137376400.png          This is my struct radio : struct Radio {
    char nom[255];
    char logo[255];
    char lien[255];
};                                                                           Images URL come from a file that I read earlier in my code :      RMC http://vipicecast.yacast.net/rmc http://www.logotheque.fr/6396-2/logo+RMC+INFO.jpg
Radio FG http://radiofg.impek.com/fg6.mp3 http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/14/Ectac.FG-Dj-Radio-logo.03.jpeg

Comment: try to use multifilesrc to compine the photos together

Comment: I can't because multifilesrc is for files from your computer not from a website